# Passing variable from template to views function in django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to pass a few variables from a template (dropdown form) to a views function. The views functions is not the same, its a different views function.

Following is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from polls.models import Choice, Poll
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.views import generic
from django.core.files import File
import os

#a = []
#c = []
def table(request,host,port):
#       host = request.GET['servers']
#       port = request.GET['instances']
#       os.system("redis-cli -h %(host)s -p %(port)s info > /home/ravi/python/info_file/%(host)s_%(port)s.txt" % locals())
        os.system("redis-cli -h %(host)s -p %(port)s info > /home/ravi/python/info_file/%(host)s_%(port)s.txt" % locals())
        with open('/home/ravi/python/info_file/%(host)s_%(port)s.txt' % locals()) as f:
                a = []
                c = []
                for line in f:
                        if not line.startswith('#'):
#                               line = line.strip()
                                if line.strip():
                                        b = line.split(':', 1)
                                        a.append(b[0])
                                        c.append(b[1])
                context = { 'key': a, 'value': c }
        return render(request, 'polls/table.html', context)
        f.close()

def redis(request):
        print "I am here"
        #print request.GET['servers']
        return render(request, 'polls/redis.html')
```

Following are the templates.

redis.html

```
<form action="{% url polls:table %} " method="get">
        <select name="servers">
                <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select the server</option>
                <option value="x.x.x.x">server_name</option>
                <option value="x.x.x.x">server_name</option>
        </select>

        <select name="instances">
                <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select the redis instance</option>
                <option value="port">redis_instance</option>
                <option value="port">redis_instance</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Second template.

table.html

```
{% load multifor %}
{% if key %}
    <table border="1" style="width:300px">
    {% for x in key; y in value %}
        <tr>
           <!-- <td>{{ x }}</td> -->
            <td>{{ x }}</td>
            <td>{{ y }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% else %}
    <p>No info available for this instance.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Following is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

    from polls import views

    urlpatterns = patterns('',

        url(r'^$', views.redis, name='redis'),
        url(r'^index/$', views.table, name='table'),
    )
```

I'll load the redis.html first at my localhost which will display two dropdown boxes and a submit button. I want to send the values selected at the dropdown boxes to be sent to views.table() function. I know one thing that I have to pass the values via URL only but I am not able to do it properly.

Comment: usually `request.GET`(in views) catches variable in a list from templates.

Comment: Yes, i get that part. But is anything supposed to be passed in the form action part so that i jump to the desired views method ?

Comment: Thats url you suppose to place in form action. using that url, you can access desired view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values are passed back to the view in a GET request. You can access them in your views.table function by:

```
if request.GET:
    values = request.GET
    print values
```

Keep in mind that the `value` attribute in the option tags in your template should be unique so that you can differentiate these variables in the GET request.

Comment: Since the drop down box is displayed at views.redis and i have to pass the variable to views.table and the views method is called when a particular url is submitted. So do i have to make any changes in the redis.html form action ?

Comment: change the form header in your template to `<form action="/table/" method="get">` presuming /table/ is the URL/view that you'd like to send the get request to.

Comment: Thanks @jogarock. Resolved it. Changed the urls.py and redis.html and got the desired result.